PineScript is exiting strategy and opening a double sized order on the same bar (sending webhook with double the quantity to the broker)
Using the pine script editor in TradingView, I've noticed a strange occurrence. When there are triggers to exit a long trade and a trigger to enter a short trade on the same bar, the position has 2x the position size than I would expect. It does not have effect on the Profit/loss calculations but send webhook request to my broker with 2x the intended quantity.
Any strategy using strategy.entry("ID1",streategy.long) then strategy.entry("ID2",streategy.short) produces these results. So the question I have is how do I prevent strategy for displaying this behavior and sending 2x the intended quantity to the broker. Here is an example:
I tried following strategy and expected the quantity of the trade to be 1.
/@version=5
strategy("BarUpDn Strategy", overlay=true, default_qty_type = strategy.fixed, default_qty_value = 1)
maxIdLossPcnt = input.float(1, "Max Intraday Loss(%)")
strategy.risk.max_intraday_loss(maxIdLossPcnt, strategy.percent_of_equity)
if (close > open and open > close[1])
    strategy.entry("BarUp", strategy.long)
if (close < open and open < close[1])
    strategy.entry("BarDn", strategy.short)

But the resulting chart and quantity send to the broker using webhook was 2.

Any recommendation on avoiding webhook sending 2x the ordered quantity would be appreciated.

Out of curiosity how do you call your broker with webhook? There is no alert_message in your trade orders (which can be customized to have a JSON payload). Also I would like to find a broker that is able to handle Tradingview's webhook but up until now could not find one. Thanks.

The alert is not defined in the script but when you create strategy alert you can format alert message as per example:
{
"ticker": "{{ticker}}",
"action": "{{strategy.order.action}}",
"sentiment": "{{strategy.market_position}}",
"quantity": "{{strategy.order.contracts}}",
"price": "{{close}}",
"time": "{{timenow}}"
}
There is no broker that accepts webhook directly from TradingView that I know of but there are third party services that you can send the JSON formatted webbook to. They in turn will send it to broker. I am using TradersPost as the intermediary.

Thanks, I'm using 3Commas.io for crypto but I needed something for regular markets. I'll check Traderspost in the future, the currently do not support my broker, Oanda.

Hedging is not allowed on Tradingview. Therefore, when you switch direction, it first closes the open order and then changes direction.
So, if you are in a long position with +1 contract and want to go short, you first need to close that long position with -1 and then go short with another -1. Hence, it is -2.
If you want to see +/- 1 on your chart, you can call strategy.close() before strategy.entry() and close the open positions yourself.
if (close > open and open > close[1])
    strategy.close("BarDn")
    strategy.entry("BarUp", strategy.long)
if (close < open and open < close[1])
    strategy.close("BarUp")
    strategy.entry("BarDn", strategy.short)


